# Compartir contenido de un card en flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

me gustaría saber cual sería la mejor forma de implementar una funcion de compartir el texto de un card en redes sociales, estas card se generan mediante un listview.builder y la idea seria añadir esta función implementando un botón de share dentro de la propia card.
gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el plugin `share_plus` creado por la comunidad Flutter:

https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

Una vez que lo agregues en el `pubspec.yaml`, la manera de usarlo es sencilla:

Import

```dart
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
```

Luego en tu lista, le agregas un `GestureDetector` implementando el `onTap`, obtienes el elemento que quieres compartir y luego usas los métodos del plugin, hay varios, te recomiendo leer los ejemplos, este es uno básico:

```dart
Share.share('Texto', subject: 'Asunto');
```

Aquí encuentras el proyecto de ejemplo de ese plugin: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/tree/main/packages/share_plus/share_plus/example

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! ha sido mas sencillo de implementar de lo que pensaba gracias a tu comentario. un abrazo.